# Why do the Roots theme CSS files not load (404)?

Tags: git, theme-roots

I've set up my new shiny 3.5.1 WordPress using Git, following these instructions: 
http://clintberry.com/2011/speed-up-your-wordpress-development-cycle-with-git/

(stopping after step 2; I've not created the child theme yet). I would expect the Roots theme to work by itself)

What I basically have is the same as the author's Git project:
https://github.com/clintberry/WordPress

What I've ended up with is  tags in the head section like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/app.css">
```

I've checked in Chrome using the Web Inspector, and it tries to load

```
http://antonyh.co.uk/assets/css/app.css
```

and returns a 404 file not found.

Why do these files not work?

Is there some magic I need to inject somewhere to make it load the CSS from the themes folder (which has roots/assets/css/app.css)?

I've not activated the theme yet, as I don't want a broken site. I could fix this with rewrite rules but that somehow feels wrong. Any help or clues would be appreciated.

Comment: roots adds rewrite rules to your htaccess file to handle requests for /assets/ in the file /lib/htaccess.php. do you have mod_rewrite and is your htaccess file writable?

Comment: Yes everything is writable and I do have mod_rewrite. Should there be a .htaccess in wp-content/themes/roots ? Or does it alter the .htaccess file in the site root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a risk and activated the theme to see what might happen. Roots needs to complete theme activation to add the rules into .htaccess. Until this happens none of the CSS / JS will load and the theme preview lacks stylesheets.

It turns the stock .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule .*\.git/.* - [F]
</IfModule>
```

into something much longer, including

```
RewriteRule ^assets/css/(.*) /wp-content/themes/roots/assets/css/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^assets/js/(.*) /wp-content/themes/roots/assets/js/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^assets/img/(.*) /wp-content/themes/roots/assets/img/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^plugins/(.*) /wp-content/plugins/$1 [QSA,L]
```

It also adds the Boilerplate HTML .htaccess rules, and removed my .git rule; I'm going to add it back in for safety despite testing showing that the Git folders are not accessible.